# What is the purpose of App Service Stack Settings?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

[image: General settings tab]

What is the purpose of Stack settings in Azure App Service? I have .NET Core 3.1 app running without problems in App Service with Stack settings as on picture above. Should I modify my ARM Template to set Stack to .NET Core?

Answer (score 2):

On windows OS that is only for initial creation.

> After initial web app creation, there isn’t a need to identify that an
>   app is a .NET Core app anymore because the .NET Core bits are already
>   installed on the underlying worker. However for *Linux* App Service
>   the stack settings will reflect .NET Core for an app, even after its
>   created.
>   [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0012bf64-b30e-4287-b8f5-68c767af887d/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-settings-in-azure-app-service?forum=AzureAPIApps)

Comment: I saw that on forum. But I don't understand it. What does it mean after "initial web app creation"? So do I need to set it during app service creation? I'm not setting anything in my ARM template and I get .NET. And the last sentence I don't understand at all.

Comment: "initial web app creation" refers to creating the web app service in the portal. If you have .net app on a windows OS, after you created the app, no need to change this settings.